# I am trying to get both marquees to stop on the click of the button. How should I name the marquees and how to tell them to stop properly?

Tags: marquee

```
<marquee behavior="scroll" direction="left" class="mymarquee">
</marquee>
<marquee behavior="scroll"; class="mymarquee"><img src="http://www.worldpeace-uk.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/smiley-face.jpg" width="100" height="100" alt="smile"></marquee>
```

Both Marquees with the class of "mymarquee

```
    <input type="button" value="Stop Marquee" onClick="document.getElementByClassName('#mymarquee').stop();">
    <input type="button" value="Start Marquee" onClick="document.getElementByClassName('#mymarquee').start();">
```

I try and tell them to stop, but nothing happens when I call them.